# What bonding allows chloroaluminate (AlCl4-) to form?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, metal

How is $\ce{AlCl4-}$ formed when $\ce{Al}$ only has $3$ electrons in it's outershell. It would be able to give $3$ electrons away with $\ce{AlCl3}$ for it to have a full outershell but how does it give another one away to the 4th $\ce{Cl}$? Wouldn't that cause it to be unstable as it wouldn't have a full outershell anymore? Also why would the final product $\ce{AlCl4}$ be negative? Wouldn't it be positive as it is giving electrons away?

Comment: Better to think of it as a covalent compound instead of an ionic compound.

Comment: If it was a covalent compound the 3 electrons would again be used to form the 3 bonds and so it wouldn't have any other electrons to donate to the 4th Cl?

Comment: See: [Dative Bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_covalent_bond)

Comment: Of course, but after forming three bonds, Al would only have six electrons around it, so there's room for two more from a chloride ion.

Comment: So chlorine forms a dative bond with the Al by donating 2 electrons to the covalent bond? But then the Cl wouldn't have a full outer shell as it requires 1 electron from the Al but the Al doesn't have one to give.

Comment: Chloride doesn't donate outright, it shares the electrons in a covalent bond with the aluminum. Yes, the aluminum has a **formal charge** of 3+ but it can covalently bond with 4 chlorides, each sharing 2 electrons to have a full octet of electrons in the n=3 shell. Boron does the same thing for the n=2 shell.

Comment: In order for the covalent bond to work wouldn't the Al need an electron? It has 3 in its outer shell and 1 is shared in each bond within ALCl3. It wouldn't have another electron to share with the Cl in the 4th Cl covalent bond?

Comment: Also the Cl would share 2 electrons with the Al but would only recieve 1 in return from the Al for it to have a full outershell that wouldn't work would it as both have to donate the same amount to the bond unless its dative? Also I thought covalent bonds were only between 2 non metals?

Comment: Think of it as $\ce{Al^{3+} + 4 Cl- -> [AlCl4]-}$.

Comment: So the 4th chlorine doesn't gain an electron from the Al and instead shares 2 of its own?

Comment: Correct. The same pattern is present in the aluminium trichloride dimer and in solid aluminium trichloride. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Aluminium-trichloride-dimer-3D-balls.png and https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Aluminium-trichloride-crystal-3D-balls.png

Comment: Thank you for your help. 1 Last question, if it is dative covalent bonding as the lone pair from the Cl is being shared with the Al how come it isn't drawn as dative covalent bonding?

Comment: @James There are quite a number of ways to look at this situation. We can see it as: an aluminium ion in the centre with 4 chloride ligands surrounding it. Each chloride ligand donates a lone pair of electrons. The net result is an aluminion atom covalently bonded to an aluminium atom with a -1 formal charge. Most of the time, this would be indicated outside of the square brackets to indicate that the charge is delocalised over the entire complex ion. Why do we represent it without the dative bonds? Well... Dative covalent bonds and covalent bonds with formal charges are the same.

Comment: In this case, we would rather use formal charges because it would be weird to show each chloride ion having a negative charge and the aluminium ion still having the +3 charge in the overall structure